Create Journal Entry Sage Business Cloud
I am trying to create a journal entry for Sage Business Cloud, but I receive a 500 internal server error. Does anyone have some sample JSON? Here is the spec:
https://developer.sage.com/sage-network-api/reference/production/#tag/JournalEntries
Here is the JSON that I use. I get a 500 internal server error:
POST
[{"Source":0,"PostingDate":"2024-06-05T09:07:50.7738748-04:00","Status":0,"Description":"Joe","Comment":"Joe","ReferenceNumber":"Reference","SourcePostingDate":"0001-01-01T00:00:00","Created":"0001-01-01T00:00:00","CreatedUserId":"7f2c51b9-18c0-46af-9bcf-ad6d47d47c1a","Modified":"0001-01-01T00:00:00","SourceModifiedDate":"0001-01-01T00:00:00","Lines":[{"AccountNumber":"5010","AccountName":"Cost of Goods Sold - Inventory \u0026 Materials","Debit":0,"Credit":100,"CurrencyCode":"USD","BaseDebit":0,"BaseCredit":100,"BaseCurrencyCode":"USD","Memo":"Test","SourceObjectType":0,"Created":"0001-01-01T00:00:00","Modified":"0001-01-01T00:00:00","SourceModifiedDate":"0001-01-01T00:00:00"},{"AccountNumber":"1205","AccountName":"Inventory","Debit":100,"Credit":0,"CurrencyCode":"USD","BaseDebit":100,"BaseCredit":0,"BaseCurrencyCode":"USD","Memo":"Test","SourceObjectType":0,"Created":"0001-01-01T00:00:00","Modified":"0001-01-01T00:00:00","SourceModifiedDate":"0001-01-01T00:00:00"}]}] 
I posted the JSON. I tried commenting the lines element and I receive a validation error. I know that the endpoint is correct. There are no authentication issues.
